# Destroy method does not reset the chart index

Tags: highcharts

Here is the problem. I want to destroy the existing chart and replace with a new instance. As per doc, I need to call destroy() method and then create a new one. But even if I do so, the Highcharts array still keep the old reference (as undefined) and create the new chart with new index.

Below is the example code, [also in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdfahim/hzcon0La/1/). Just click on the button and you will see the chart index is increasing.

```
createChart();
function createChart(){
    var options ={
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            .................
            .................
        }
    }
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    alert(chart.index)
}

function newChart(){
    $("#container").highcharts().destroy();
    createChart();
}
$("#button").click(function(){
    newChart();
}
```

Comment: This is behaving as the documentation says it should http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.charts.  The object is being destroyed.  Is there a reason you care about  the chart index?

Comment: Thanks, I found that later while searching .. actually I am creating a complex chart (with multiple chart in same container with synchronized tooltip, crosshair etc.). So, for that I need to override several mousehover actions where I need the chart index in the Highcharts array to access specific charts. Now, with chart index are changing, it becomes unusable. Anyhow, I just used some extra if conditions to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest creating a high chart on click of a button. Instead you can simply add and remove series (opposed to create and destroy). You can use hide()/unhide() operations if you want to hide a serious temporarily. Hope this helps.